# How to hack phpMyAdmin CSS to change some properties of the tables' headers?

Tags: css, phpmyadmin

**Description:** 
Like many of you I user phpMyAdmin alot during a day. It is all satisfying, but i have a big problem. When you view a table's record, you would probably scroll down the page (since 99% you have more than 8-9 records..). When you scroll down the page, the header are lost, and it is quite weird for you to find a certain column among 20 other columns.

**My Question:**
How is it possible to hack the CSS of the php admin, which I assume is not a raw css?
I want to apply some CSS rule to the table header to keep it fixed when the page is scrolled.

Comment: You could use a userscript.. though I suggest rewording the question. You aren't looking to hacking anything.

Comment: If I directly edit some CSS stuff of phpMyAdmin then it accounts for hacking. anyway, you suggestion is worth researching, thanks alot

Comment: PHPMyAdmin supports custom CSS files, I believe. That is not hacking.

Comment: If you are on chrome, you can use TamperMonkey to change some styling using client-side Javascript

Answer (score 1):

When I go to my `phpMyAdmin` folder, there is a folder `Themes` that contains two folders. In both folders there is a `css` folder. I guess you can change some CSS styles there.

Answer (score 1):

Go to phpmydamin folder which would be in `wamp\apps` usually.

And if for example you want to change the size of inline editor in phpmyadmin go to:

```
C:\wamp\apps\phpmyadmin4.1.14\themes\pmahomme\css\codemirror.css.php
```

Open the file `codemirror.css.php`

In that file find this block

```
#inline_editor_outer .CodeMirror {
    height: <?php echo ceil($GLOBALS['cfg']['TextareaRows'] *0.4; ?>em;
}
```

and change that `0.4` to a bigger number like `2.0` in my case

```
#inline_editor_outer .CodeMirror {
    height: <?php echo ceil($GLOBALS['cfg']['TextareaRows'] *2.0; ?>em;
}
```

And you are good to go.

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu 16.04, you should take a look on this directory: **`/usr/share/phpmyadmin/js`**, or this: **`/usr/share/phpmyadmin/theme`**. For example, I find the CSS file that I need to change in **`.../phpmyadmin/js/codemirror/lib/codemirror.css`**.