# Is it possible to increase the font size in phpmyadmin textarea?

Tags: phpmyadmin

I use LMDE with two 1920x1080 monitors, and the text is really small, after a while the eyes get very tired.

[image]

I tried increasing the zoom in firefox, but the text becomes blurred and it's even worse.

For this site I don't want to create an administration, I would like to continue using phpmyadmin to add content, but after a while my eyes really start to hurt ...

Is it possible to increase the font size, perhaps even modifying some phpmyadmin files?

In the settings I have looked everywhere but I have not found anything that allows to increase the font size in the textarea.

---

**UPDATE**

Sorry guys, I came back today after a flu.

I tried 3-4 different ways that you suggested, but it never seems to change anything ...

Also restarted the server, etc but nothing.

The text increases a bit by increasing the percentage in home-> apperance, but to see a minimum increase, the percentage must increase a lot and everything else becomes ridiculously large ...

Is it possible that you can't increase this damn font?

Comment: I'm not really good at PHP but as I have read in your question, you used CSS to increase the font size, right?

Comment: ok, but this is phpmyadmin... it is not mine...

Comment: oh... so why don't you copy and paste the text onto a word document or something and then increase the font?

Comment: Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22816991/increase-font-size-of-sql-query-box

Comment: Here you go https://stackoverflow.com/a/39082065/6215280

Answer (score 1):

Follow below steps to increased font in phpmyadmin.

1. Go to directory

> xampp > phpMyAdmin > themes > pmahomme > css

2. Open the below

> codemirror.css.php

3. Add or update the following line to the file

> .CodeMirror pre {font-size:1.4em;}

Save the file and that should do it!

Let me know if you issue not solved.

Comment: Hi, sorry, don't seems to work, I added this .CodeMirror pre {font-size:1.4em;} and this .CodeMirror textarea {font-size:1.4em;} at the end of the file /usr/share/phpmyadmin/themes/pmahomme/css/codemirror.css.php and restart my server, but nothing changed...

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to change the CSS of the PHPMyAdmin. Depending on installation you should look for a file called "codemirror.css.php".
Here is some other similar question about change another element on the PHPMyAdmin
[How to hack phpMyAdmin CSS to change some properties of the tables' headers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20589161/how-to-hack-phpmyadmin-css-to-change-some-properties-of-the-tables-headers)